# JavaScript Library, how to return if no action

Tags: javascript

Im making a small Library that will help small/large functions in my Library... it all works fine but if I just want to return the object I want to do it like so `_(".class");` just like jQuery's one...

This is the base code for my one...

```
var Test = function(elm){
                if(elm != undefined){
                    Test.DOMSelection(elm);
                }


                return {
                    html:function(newHTML){
                        return Test.html(newHTML);
                    }
                };
            };
```

How can I test if anything is at the end after the selector like _(".class").bla <-- This bla is at the end... how do i test if their is anything there?

Comment: I feel a lack of low-level programming skills. Few months with Pascal could save you few years questioning on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: not possible.

Only previous computations (function inputs and current state) can be used, not further computations in the chain which have not occurred yet. (JavaScript has no notion of exposed "expression trees" although the "builder pattern" can achieve similar results with a far more verbose syntax.)

If `bla` is a function (and called as such) or a getter property, and the appropriate logic is added to the function (or getter), then that logic can trigger *when* `bla` is evaluated which is *after* `class` finishes.

---

jQuery uses method chaining; each jQuery method that can be chained returns a *new* jQuery object. However, jQuery never looks ahead - which is not possible in JavaScript - as to what will be called next. Consider this:

```
// Find *all* DIVs on the page
x1 = $('div');
// and for all the DIVs *previously found*, which are accessible by x1,
// find the one that has a given class
x2 = x1.filter('.foo');
```

Note that both x1 and x2 name *different* jQuery objects. The elements in x1 were obtained by the applying the inputs (the html form, and the selector) while the elements in x2 were found by applying the inputs (the elements in x1, and the selector) to obtain the output (the matched elements in x2).

Comment: How does jQuery do it then? as if you just go $(".class") It just returns the object and nothing else...

Comment: @ryanc1256 $(..) returns a *new* jQuery object, or a "set of elements". Additional jQuery *methods* can be invoked upon it to expand/refined or manipulate the given "set of elements". However, jQuery doesn't "look ahead". Each jQuery method executes on the input (existing state and function arguments) and returns some output.

Comment: so how do you implement this in JavaScript, is it quite hard?

Comment: @ryanc1256 I added a small example, which should hopefully clear up how jQuery works. Basically, jQuery propagates state in the *new* objects that it returns.